# Javascript Clear DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am wanting to completely clear the DOM with Javascript.

I have tried a few things, like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = "";
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

Interestingly, clearing the head like this will generate an error ("invalid target element for this operation") in IE, but will successfully clear the head in Chrome. However, clearing the body like this works in IE but fails silently in Chrome.

I have also tried

```
document.childNodes.length = 0;
```

but this is apparently a read-only property and won't do anything.

Is there a good cross-browser way to clear the DOM?

Comment: my question will be what are you trying to accomplish with this exactly. be cause i cant think of a situation where you need to do this

Comment: Jeez, people always ask me that on all of my questions. Even if you can't think of a good reason why you would want to programmatically clear the DOM, I still want to do it. If you like, just assume that I just arbitrarily want to do it for fun.

Comment: So, you are executing javascript that's in your page and you want to clear the javascript you're running at the moment from the page?  Sounds like a problem to me.

Comment: As for asking why you'd want to do this, that's a perfectly reasonable question.  It's an odd thing to do, many of us don't know how to do it so if you don't explain what you're really trying to accomplish, then you have no chance of soliciting other ways to solve your problem (whatever the problem is).

Comment: @jfriend00 I am fairly certain that Javascript will continue to run even if the script tag is cleared from the DOM, but once it has been cleared it can no longer be called externally.

Comment: @jfriend00: thank you for making it clear. We are not the code police, explaining what you are trying to accomplish will help us give you a good solution. Being all rude about it, and playing the smarty pants is just childish

Comment: @jfriend00 I am trying to accomplish a function that will completely clear the page. The problem is as simple as that. No overlooked alternatives.

Comment: @Ibu I am sorry if I came across as rude and arrogant. It is not my intention. I'm simply trying to say that what I am trying to accomplish is exactly what the question is asking for. If you were the downvoter, could you please explain how that is worthy of a downvote?

Comment: @Peter - That isn't actually your end objective since it doesn't do anything useful all by itself, but obviously you don't care to share that.  Never mind, I'll move on to other questions.

Comment: @jfriend00, JavaScript does not have to be located in the DOM. It can be located on the computer locally. For example, see User JS and extensions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works...

```
document.removeChild(document.documentElement);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv2xK/).

Note that the browser will leave the doctype intact.

Comment: How come no one mentioned document.write() ?

Answer (score 3):

Setting `document`'s `innerHTML` is [officially supported in HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml), but not in HTML4.

This should work in HTML4:

```
var html = document.documentElement;
while(html.firstChild){
    html.removeChild(html.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is useful example, not perfect but can use

```
/**
 * clear child nodes
 * @param {HTMLElement} node
 */
    clearChildren : function(node) {
        if (!node) {
            return;
        }
        if(node.innerHTML){
            node.innerHTML = '';
            return;
        }
        while (node.childElementCount > 0) {
        var child = node.childNodes.item(0);
        if(isIE){
            child.onmousedown = null;
            child.onmouseover = null;
            child.onmouseout = null;
            child.onclick = null;
            child.oncontextmenu = null;
        }
        node.removeChild(child);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not cross browser, Opera has a writable `outerHTML` property.

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be much simpler

```
document.write();
```

Comment: In 2022 this generates a warning message in the Chrome console: "Avoid using document.write()"